# Overriding Object equals method

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two arrays using the Object equals method that i am overriding. I am supposed to cast the object parameter to ListInterface and i can't seem to figure out what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class AList<T extends Comparable> implements ListInterface <T> {

    private T[] list;
    private int length;
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50;

    public AList()
    {
        this(MAX_SIZE);
    }
    public AList(int maxSize)
    {
        length = 0;
        list = (T[]) new AList[maxSize];
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {

        boolean results = true;
        if (list.length == ((ListInterface<T>) other).getLength())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                if(list[i].equals((ListInterface<T>)other[i]))
                    results = true;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more detail about just what is wrong or just how you're stuck. Note that I'd check for null first, and then check for reference equality before checking other stuff. i.e., `if (other == null) return false;` and `if (other == this) return true;` Then I'd check instanceof *before* casting.

Comment: Is an instance of an AList<T..> supposed to possibly be equal to to an instance of a different class that implements ListInterface<T>? This might violate the .equals(Object o) invariant that if a.equals(b) is true, b.equals(a) should also be true.

Answer (score 4):

It appears your equals method is trying to check whether the two arrays that the objects encapsulate contain the same objects. Arrays.deepEquals(T[] t1, T[] t2) may be able to help.

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if(other == null || ! (other instanceof AList<T>))
        return false;
    AList<T> a = (AList<T>)other;
    return Arrays.deepEquals(list, a.list); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if `other` is *not* a `ListInterface<T>`? What will

```
myListInterface.equals(new StringBuilder());
```

do? (Answer is it throws an `InvalidCastException` or something). Casting is only capable of changing the type of things for primitives, e.g. `int` to `boolean` It is *not* capable of changing the type of objects. Casting an array to a list does not make it a list, it just makes it something that's going to throw an error every time you try to call a list method that the object doesn't have. It's usually a sign you have bad polymorphic design, but this method is an exception. It means you need to use `instanceof` first.

Overriding `equals` is hard. Try autogenerating one from Eclipse or IntelliJ to see the work that goes into it, or look up a default override implementation online.

Comment: here is some suggestions from my teacher. "This method should override the equals method from the Object class. The method header should reflect this and you will need to cast the parameter from Object to ListInterface." First first array is from a AList class that implements ListInterface<T>. Second array was created in the main test test the methods.

the two arrays that are being compared are below.
T [] list = (T[]) new AList[maxSize]
AList<String> otherNames = new AList<String>();